# Team foundation server source control Tutorial

Tags: version-control, team-foundation-server

Is here someone who can write me a good tutorial to understand the TFS source control system?

There is some functionalities I didn't really understand like reservations, extractions, some mysterious icons, etc..

Thanks

Comment: Super User is not the kind of place to ask for links to tutorials. If you have any *specific* and answerable question about how to use TFS, please [edit] your post to include that.

Comment: Is ther an another stack exchange for tutorials?.. Anything I ask here somebody say to me.. "This is not the good place.." It is pretty complicated to understand why I can ask about some help on a help based web portal..

Comment: Well, the only thing Stack Exchange requires is for you to write a specific question that can be answered. Links to some websites are no answers, as these might become outdated, or even deleted. In your current question, what could the possible answer be for *> There is some functionalities I didn't really understand like reservations, extractions, some mysterious icons*? Again, please **ask a specific question**. What do you want to know about reservations and extractions? Is the manual not helpful for you? Which icons are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751354/any-tutorial-manual-for-tfs-team-explorer) is links for documentation.. Maybe you ll find something who help you

Comment: @bAN I'm just being curious, did that help you in any way? As far as I can see there's only a link to a guide.

Comment: Not totally you'r right but my question seems to be badly writted and poor.. so I assume this answer is better enough.. I will search for more informations in another places.